# How to access variable within .done() method in AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Context**

I have a function that is called within an AJAX call that returns a number. I set this number to a variable and want to access the number outside of the `.done()` method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'urlhere.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {text: text},
    success: function(data) {

        var getNumber = countNumber();
        getNumber.done(function(data) {

            var number = data;

        });

        let newContent = 
        "The number is "+
        number;

    }
});
```

But I get this error, stating that the variable is not defined:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: number is not defined
```

**Question**

How do I access variables within the `.done()` method in jQuery in an AJAX call?

**Things I Have Tried**

I have already tried defining the variable before the function call and then changing it in the `done()` method, like so:

```
var number; //initialize variable

$.ajax({
    url: 'urlhere.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {text: text},
    success: function(data) {

        var getNumber = countNumber();
        getNumber.done(function(data) {

            number = data;

        });

        let newContent = 
        "The number is "+
        number; //console.log's "undefined"

    }
});
```

This only makes the variable equal to `undefined`, so I don't think anything inside the `done()` method is able to change existing variables. Any ideas? Let me know if there is any confusion. Thanks.

Comment: Try putting your ajax call in a function, and just before calling the function, make sure the "number" variable is declared and defined with desired value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `getNumber.done()` is asyncronous. Which means it takes a while to update the the value of `number`;

You may do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'urlhere.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {text: text},
    success: function(data) {

        var getNumber = countNumber();
        getNumber.done(function(data) {

            number = data;
            let newContent = "The number is "+ number; //console.log's "undefined"
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the code is asynchronous so the number variable won't be assigned just after you can the done() function.

```
var getNumber = countNumber();
getNumber.done(function(data) {

    number = data;

});

// number won't exist here.
let newContent =   "The number is "+ number; //console.log's "undefined"
```

What you can do:

- Use a promise and use resolve on the done() callback. You will need to await after it.
- Call a function from .done() callback and keep your process from there

Something like this:

```
    var getNumber = countNumber();
    getNumber.done(function(data) {

        number = data;
        // Your code should flow from here.
        yourDoneFunction();
    });
```